# Get count of records affected by INSERT or UPDATE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

My database driver for PostgreSQL 8/9 does not return a count of records affected when executing `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

PostgreSQL offers the non-standard syntax "[RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)" which seems like a good workaround. But what might be the syntax? The example returns the ID of a record, but I need a count.

> INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets')
>      **RETURNING did**;

Comment: I know it doesn't sound helpful but you have to find better drivers or update for your current ones (the solution OMG Ponies have posted works only in PL/pgSQL code).

Comment: MySQL automatically outputs rows matched vs. rows affected for updates, pity the psql driver can't do the same.

Comment: Not tried this.. but does `INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets') RETURNING 1;` work?

Comment: I tried with latest PostgreSQL and JDBC drivers. It seems to return 1 for successful inserts. Haven't tried update.

Answer (score 157):

I know this question is oooolllllld and my solution is arguably overly complex, but that's my favorite kind of solution!

Anyway, I had to do the same thing and got it working like this:

```
-- Get count from INSERT
WITH rows AS (
    INSERT INTO distributors
        (did, dname)
    VALUES
        (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets'),
        (DEFAULT, 'ABC Widgets')
    RETURNING 1
)
SELECT count(*) FROM rows;

-- Get count from UPDATE
WITH rows AS (
    UPDATE distributors
    SET dname = 'JKL Widgets'
    WHERE did <= 10
    RETURNING 1
)
SELECT count(*) FROM rows;
```

One of these days I really have to get around to writing a love sonnet to PostgreSQL's WITH clause ...

Comment: How to assign the count to variable and RAISE NOTICE??

Comment: @Udhaya to assign: `SELECT ... INTO var FROM ...;`, to raise notice: `RAISE NOTICE '%', var;`.

Comment: But if you updated 0 rows, `SELECT count(*) FROM rows;` will not return 0. It will return no records. That's a problem.

Comment: @peter.petrov I didn't find this. I got count 0 with pg11. Is it a bug of old version?

Comment: I disagree with "my solution is arguably overly complex", this is fantastic.

Comment: @mercurial I'd love to read that love sonnet if you ever finished it.

Comment: Can you rewrite it as one-liner so I can use it in my api? (sql statements are parameters for db.js)

Answer (score 40):

I agree w/ Milen, your driver should do this for you. What driver are you using and for what language? But if you are using plpgsql, you can use `GET DIAGNOSTICS my_var = ROW_COUNT;`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS

Comment: It's humorous because this is the (now deleted and hidden) answer @OMGPonies gave in 2010.

Answer (score 31):

You can take `ROW_COUNT` after update or insert with this code:

```
insert into distributors (did, dname) values (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets');
get diagnostics v_cnt = row_count;
```

Comment: seems that only work in code block

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your query in a transaction and it should show you the count before you `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT`. Example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT .... ;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

If you run the first 2 lines of the above, it should give you the count. You can then `ROLLBACK` (undo) the insert if you find that the number of affected lines isn't what you expected. If you're satisfied that the `INSERT` is correct, then you can run the same thing, but replace line 3 with `COMMIT TRANSACTION;`.

**Important note:** After you run any `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` you *must* either `ROLLBACK;` or `COMMIT;` the transaction, otherwise the transaction will create a lock that can slow down or even cripple an entire system, if you're running on a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question how you're calling the statement. Assuming you're using something like JDBC you may be calling it as a query rather than an update. From JDBC's [`executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29):

> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet
>   object.

This is therefore appropriate when you execute a statement that returns some query results, such as `SELECT` or `INSERT ... RETURNING`. If you are making an update to the database and then want to know how many tuples were affected, you need to use [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) which returns:

> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML)
>   statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing