# Postgres UPDATE giving error

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I've got a Postgres DB with a table named "precipitazione". What I want to do is update its column "quantita" when it shows a value of -9999.
My statement :

```
 UPDATE precipitazione SET quantita = 0 WHERE quantita = -9999;
```

is not working(It is not working in the sense that the query won't be executed. It gives me a syntax error "near SET") I also tried to set "quantita" to DEFAULT (which is zero),but it's still not working.

```
SELECT * FROM precipitazione WHERE quantita = -9999;
```

is working.

Postgres VERSION: PostgreSQL 9.3.10

Comment: Not working is very vague.

Comment: It is not working in the sense that the query won't be executed. It gives me a syntax error.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your update statement. Is this the only statement in the batch that you are trying to execute?

Comment: And what **is** the (exact) error?

Comment: It is in italian but I believe it is comprehensible. A rough translation would be:
SQL ERROR:

ERROR: syntax error in or near "SET"
LINE 1: ...ECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE precipitazione SET quanti...

The original error below:
"Errore SQL:

ERRORE:  errore di sintassi a o presso "SET"
LINE 1: ...ECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (UPDATE precipitazione SET quanti..."

Comment: You cannot wrap an update in a select like that. If you want to get a count of rows affected by the update take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25941849/1175077

Comment: The error message doesn't match the statement you have shown us. How and with which tool are you running this update? If you are _really_ running the update as shown, then your SQL tool messes with the statement.

Comment: If you are using **phppgadmin** this is a known bug. Your query is ok, try it in psql.

Comment: klin, you nailed it! ;) That was it. Can you post a link to a list of this "known bugs" sir/lady?